# Error while trying to upload file using kairos

Tags: python, image, opencv, request, python-requests

Iam using kairos api for face recognition .Iam trying to enroll an image.The [documentation](https://www.kairos.com/docs/api/#post-enroll) here says it also accepts base64 encode photos.So I have encoded the image using base 64 and I get the following error

```
{"Errors":[{"ErrCode":5000,"Message":"an invalid image was sent must be jpg or p
ng format"}]}
```

I have used the following python code for sending the requests

```
import cv2
import requests
import base64
import json

image=cv2.imread('Face-images/Subject 9.jpg')
encoded_string =base64.b64encode(image)
payload2= {"image":encoded_string ,"subject_id":"Abhishek","gallery_name":"MyGallery"}
headers={'Content-Type':'application/json','app_id':'app_id','app_key':'app_key'}
r = requests.post('https://api.kairos.com/enroll',headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload2),verify=False)
print  r.text
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try encoded_string = base64.b64encode(open('Face-images/Subject 9.jpg', 'r').read())

Comment: Now its not showing errors .But the image is not getting uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Don't encode your photos. Probably they accept it, but its harder to pass. Check this solution:

```
import requests

files = {"image": (filename,open(location+'/'+filename,"rb"))}
payload= {"subject_id":"Abhishek",
          "gallery_name":"MyGallery"}
headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
         'app_id':'app_id',
         'app_key':'app_key'}
response = requests.post('https://api.kairos.com/enroll',headers=headers,data=payload,files=files,verify=False)
print response.text
```

Comment: Dont you know how to use similar approach when reading images from S3?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the problem. You can try reading the image not using cv2, but as simple raw binary. cv2 reads it into a numpy array and you are encoding a numpy array. Reading like a simple file works for me, like below

```
with open ('messi.jpg','rb') as imgFh:
    img = imgFh.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import cv2
import requests
import base64
import json

encoded_string = base64.b64encode(open("Face-images/Subject 9.jpg", 
'r').read())
payload_dict = {
    "image":encoded_string,
    "subject_id": "Abhishek",
    "gallery_name": "MyGallery"
}
payload = json.dumps(payload_dict)
headers={
'Content-Type':'application/json',
'app_id':'app_id',
'app_key':'app_key'
}
request = Request('https://api.kairos.com/enroll', data=payload, 
headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print(response_body)
```