# Upload local images in kairos python

Tags: python, image-uploading

Below is my code to upload file in kairos from my local machine.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

values_enroll = """
  {
    "image": "/home/neel/project/test5.jpg",
    "subject_id": "2",
    "gallery_name": "MyGallery"
  }
"""

headers_enroll = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'app_id': '2dxxxx79',
  'app_key': '08aa31ebdxxxxxxxxxxaa6f6c87f4ea8'
}

request_enroll = Request('https://api.kairos.com/enroll', 
data=values_enroll, headers=headers_enroll)
response_body_enroll = urlopen(request_enroll).read()
print response_body_enroll
```

when i run this code I get an error:

> "{"Errors":[{"ErrCode":5000,"Message":"an invalid image was sent must
>   be jpg or png format"}]}"

I'm following this documentation:http://docs.kairosv1.apiary.io/#reference/face-recognition/enroll/post .

Now instead of upload image from publicly accessible URL, I want to upload image from my local machine and it's work fine while uploading image from publicly accessible URL.

I also tried both solution given in:[Error while trying to upload file using kairos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175107/error-while-trying-to-upload-file-using-kairos)
and also solution in this:http://www.projsolution.com/a107-6007-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recently I found a solution(It worked for me):

```
files = {"image": ("test5.jpg",open("/home/neel/project/test5.jpg","rb"))}

values_enrol = """
{
   "subject_id": "2",
   "gallery_name": "MyGallery"
}
"""
res = requests.post("https://api.kairos.com/enroll", files=files, data=values_enroll, headers=headers)
```

p/s: It will work if you delete Content-Type